# Ignoring font in document (doc/docx) field merging on IIS

Tags: .net, iis, merge

I have some code to merge document using Tx Text Control (though it is not specific to Tx Text Control). after merging and saving as HTM file, the HTM file ignores some font.

```
Me.MailMerge1 = New TXTextControl.DocumentServer.MailMerge(Me.components)
Me.ServerTextControl1 = New TXTextControl.ServerTextControl()
Me.MailMerge1.ReportDataSourceConfig = ""
Me.MailMerge1.TextComponent = Me.ServerTextControl1
MailMerge1.LoadTemplate(Server.MapPath("TempDoc.docx"), TXTextControl.DocumentServer.FileFormat.WordprocessingML)
MailMerge1.Merge(ds.Tables(0))
MailMerge1.SaveDocument(Server.MapPath("~/") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString + ".htm", TXTextControl.StreamType.HTMLFormat, Nothing)
```

It works fine on local machine and directly running from Visual Studio(pressing Ctl+F5). but ignores some font after deploying on IIS (on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2012 R2).
Ex:  it ignores "Broadway" font but keeps formatting of "Courier New", "Comic Sans MS" etc.
Same issue occur with OpenXML SDK code.
It look like some issue with permission on `Fonts` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by restarting server. It was started getting font properly after restart. but I think it is not advisable solution to restart Server machine. 
Any other solution also welcome.